# Spring Service Scope Singleton multiple threads, behavior

Tags: java, spring, singleton

```
@Service
public class Example {

    public void callApi() {
        String value = callThirdPartyLibrary();
        Date date =  = callThirdPartyLibraryToGetDate();
        callMethod(value, date);
    }
}
```

In this example I have class Example with annotation Service which default scope is Singleton.
Imagine you have a lot of concurrent services calling this callApi() method. Is it possible that value and date mix the values from different threads or I can make sure that won't happen?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible. You'd be well-advised to make sure `callThirdPartyLibrary()` is thread-safe, though

Comment: Value and date are local variables which are different on each thread. So they can not mix.

Comment: This point is not about spring `@Singleton`, it's about the java memory model, especially about the stack. You can read more int this articles: [first](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html), [second](https://www.guru99.com/java-stack-heap.html)